# Adding adjacent ranges to existing range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a rather uncommon issue

I'm trying to create a named range with several areas in it.
Using that I will use the [area] method in index to retrieve my data

What I will do is to have a named range in Excel referring to several areas

MyNamedRange refersto ="A1:A3,B1:B3,C1:C3" etc.

This named range is being build with VBA so what i have is

```
For x = 1 to 10
   Set rngTemp = Range(cells(x,1), cells(x,3))
    if x > 1 then       
      Set unionRange = union(unionRange, rngTemp)
    else
      Set unionRange = rngTemp
    end if
Next x

MyWorkBook.Names.Add Name:="MyRange", RefersTo:=unionRange
```

However, this range is set to A1:C3 (and thus is not divided into several areas)

I know it is because the ranges are adjacent to each other, but is there anyway I can override this and make sure that Excel splits them up into several areas?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim MyWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long
    Dim rngTemp As Range
    Dim refR1C1 As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant workbook
    Set MyWorkBook = ThisWorkbook

    '~~> Change this to the relevant Sheet
    Set ws = MyWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        For x = 1 To 10
            Set rngTemp = Range(.Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x, 3))

            If refR1C1 = "" Then
                refR1C1 = "="
            Else
                refR1C1 = refR1C1 & .Name & "!" & rngTemp.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ","
            End If
        Next x

        refR1C1 = Left(refR1C1, Len(refR1C1) - 1)
    End With

    Debug.Print refR1C1

    MyWorkBook.Names.Add Name:="MyRange", RefersToR1C1:=refR1C1

    Debug.Print Range("MyRange").Areas.Count
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**:

[image]

Comment: Excellent! That was the solution I used, and even if it is not as nice as referring to it using a range-object, it works. However, I only referred to the sheet in the beginning of the string and that worked fine too. (But excel re-wrote it to your format).